# Can I get how much memory for my program remains?

Tags: java, android, memory

My program has many works that need a lot of memory that I can't exactly know when I need to stop it, but in case there's very few memory left, I can force it stop using resources. So can I get how many remaining (in byte) memory that my program can use?

P/s: There's NO way to release the process memory. They need memory, as much as possible, and that is how it works (and, no trash for collector, since old ones still be need).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Debug.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

String memMessage = String.format("Memory: Pss=%.2f MB,
    Private=%.2f MB, Shared=%.2f MB",
    memoryInfo.getTotalPss() / 1000,
    memoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty() / 1000,
    memoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty() / 1000);
```

You can read more at this blog: http://huenlil.pixnet.net/blog/post/26872625

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very very details, there's other useful information as well :)

Comment: Can you mark it as answered, to take it off the unanswered list.

Comment: Sure, but I need to wait for 15 mins :)

Comment: indeed! forgot about that! :)

Comment: Why the division by 1024?
Acording to Android Docs the results are in kB (multiple of 1000) and NOT in KB or KIB.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.MemoryInfo.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Answer (score 1):

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/GetHeapSize.html

Comment: Thanks, your second link is useful for quick research. +1 :)

Comment: no problem sorry I didn't write anything out didn't mean to be short with you or anything just don't know the details any more than those pages could explain, interesting issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static long getCurrentFreeMemoryBytes() {
     long heapSize =  Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
     long heapRemaining = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();   
     long nativeUsage  =  Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();

     return Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - (heapSize - heapRemaining) - nativeUsage;    
}
```

While not perfect it should do the trick for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tools that Android provides for memory tracking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryInfo%28android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo%29).