# Is there any tool/plugin that monitor application's memory usage while debugging/running

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an app that works on large images and data caching.
I am using a top end model phone which I believe can handle memory issues better than other phones.
Just want to make sure that it can also perform on other phones.
Is there any tool or application in eclipse or separate that can monitor memory usage.
Will be great If I can see the heap size; whether data is garbage collected instantly after activity finishes; etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly what you're looking for is the Heap and Allocation Tracker in the DDMS. In Eclipse, you can open the DDMS perspective by clicking `Window->Open Perspective->Other...->DDMS`.

Once in the perspective, you can click on the device you want to track, find the app you want to track in the `Devices` tab.  Click the `Update Heap` button (it's a green cylinder icon), and the `Heap` tab on the right will open.  The Allocation Track also in that perspective can be used to track object allocations.

Aside from that there is also the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) tool which may come in handy.

[DDMS documentation.](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

[Related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766898/monitor-the-memory-ocuppied-by-my-app-in-android)