# Out of Memory when using compresstojpeg on multiple YuvImage one at a time

Tags: android, image-processing, out-of-memory, yuv

I am building an app that buffers **N** camera frames and when the user taps a button it saves the photo using all the saved frames applying an effect.

I am saving the photo and processing the frames on an **AsyncTask**. When I execute it, I remove everything from the screen and leave only a **TextView** to display the progress of saving the photo.

Currently the **AsyncTask** `doInBackground` looks like this:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) 
{
    int w = mBuffer.get(0).getWidth();
    int h = mBuffer.get(0).getHeight();
    int lineHeight = h / mBuffer.size();
    int currentHeight = 0;

    Log.d("output", "saving photo "+w+", "+h);

    for (int i = 0; i < mBuffer.size(); i++)
    {
        YuvImage image = mBuffer.get(i);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (!image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, currentHeight, w, lineHeight), 50, out))
        {
            Log.d("output", "problem converting yuv to jpg");
            break;
        }

        currentHeight += lineHeight;

        Log.d("output", "currentHeight: "+currentHeight);

        publishProgress((int)((i / (float)mBuffer.size()) * 100));
        try
        {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        System.gc();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if (isCancelled())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've already removed a lot of not-so-important parts of code for this issue and this is only the part that is raising **OutOfMemory** issue. Basically what I'm doing there is getting a line from the image and compressing it to JPEG. But it only manages to compress the first image. When it goes to the second one, it raises an **OutOfMemory** exception.

The `System.GC()`, `Thread.sleep()`, `out.flush()`, `out.close()`, are all unsuccessful attemps to fix the problem.

The currently size of mBuffer is 5, initially it was 32. From the DDMS Heap debug, its Heap Size is 30MB and it is allocating 9MB. Apparently there is a lot of room to grow. If I remove the `compressToJpeg()` the **AsyncTask** completes just fine.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Should I try my own YUV -> JPEG converter?

**EDIT with most recent code:**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) 
{
    int lineHeight = mHeight / mBufferSize;
    int currentHeight = 0;

    Log.d("output", "saving photo: "+mWidth+", "+mHeight);
    File outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/camerafluid-output");
    outputPath.mkdirs();
    for (int i = 0; i < mBufferSize; i++)
    {
        File imageFile = new File(mCachePath, "image-"+0);
        File outputFile = new File(outputPath, "image-"+0);

        if (!imageFile.exists())
        {
            Log.d("output", "image "+i+" not found on cache directory");
            continue;
        }

        try
        {
            int size = (int)imageFile.length();
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[size];
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
            buf.read(imageBytes, 0, size);
            buf.close();

            YuvImage image = new YuvImage(imageBytes, ImageFormat.NV21, mWidth, mHeight, null);
            imageBytes = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (!image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, currentHeight, mWidth, lineHeight), 50, out))
            {
                Log.d("output", "problem converting yuv to jpg");
                break;
            }

            FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            s.write(out.toByteArray());
            s.flush();
            s.close();
            s = null;

            currentHeight += lineHeight;
            Log.d("output", "currentHeight: "+currentHeight);

            publishProgress((int)((i / (float)mBufferSize) * 100));
            System.gc();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if (isCancelled())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am saving the images correctly as I can see the saved files on the cache directory, here is the Activity part which saves the buffer and executes the AsyncTask:

```
public void takePhoto()
{
    Log.d("output", "taking photo");

    //vfranchi - save the buffer on the disk to free memory
    File cachePath = new File(getExternalCacheDir().getPath() + "/buffer");
    if (!cachePath.exists())
    {
        Log.d("output", "cache path doesnt exist");
        cachePath.mkdirs();
    }

    int count = 0;
    int width = mPhotoBuffer.get(0).getWidth();
    int height = mPhotoBuffer.get(0).getHeight();
    int bufferSize = mPhotoBuffer.size();
    for(YuvImage i : mPhotoBuffer)
    {
        File f = new File(cachePath, "image-"+count);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(f);
            s.write(i.getYuvData());
            s.flush();
            s.close();
            Log.d("output", "saved image "+count);
            count++;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("output", "unable to save image "+count+"\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    mPhotoBuffer = null;
    System.gc();

    SavePhotoTask task = new SavePhotoTask(this, cachePath, width, height, bufferSize);
    task.execute(0);
}
```

Logcat beggining at the taking photo method:

```
03-30 12:48:08.534: D/output(15359): taking photo
03-30 12:48:09.011: V/Camera-JNI(15359): setHasPreviewCallback: installed:0, manualBuffer:0
03-30 12:48:09.011: V/Camera-JNI(15359): get_native_camera: context=0x138520, camera=0x1eea78
03-30 12:48:09.011: V/Camera-JNI(15359): Clearing callback buffers, 0 remained
03-30 12:48:09.011: V/Camera-JNI(15359): stopPreview
03-30 12:48:09.011: V/Camera-JNI(15359): get_native_camera: context=0x138520, camera=0x1eea78
03-30 12:48:15.323: D/output(15359): saved image 0
03-30 12:48:16.628: D/output(15359): saved image 1
03-30 12:48:17.880: D/output(15359): saved image 2
03-30 12:48:19.073: D/output(15359): saved image 3
03-30 12:48:20.545: D/output(15359): saved image 4
03-30 12:48:28.089: D/output(15359): saving photo: 848, 480
03-30 12:48:33.276: D/skia(15359): onFlyCompress
03-30 12:48:35.020: D/output(15359): currentHeight: 96
03-30 12:48:44.144: D/output(15359): currentHeight: 192
03-30 12:48:52.581: D/skia(15359): onFlyCompress
03-30 12:48:52.878: I/dalvikvm-heap(15359): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.975MB for 2095120-byte allocation
03-30 12:48:53.112: I/dalvikvm-heap(15359): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.975MB for 4192272-byte allocation
03-30 12:48:53.566: I/dalvikvm-heap(15359): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.975MB for 8386576-byte allocation
03-30 12:48:54.855: I/dalvikvm-heap(15359): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.975MB for 16775184-byte allocation
03-30 12:48:56.620: I/dalvikvm-heap(15359): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 33552400-byte allocation
03-30 12:48:56.644: E/dalvikvm-heap(15359): Out of memory on a 33552400-byte allocation.
03-30 12:48:56.644: I/dalvikvm(15359): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
03-30 12:48:56.644: I/dalvikvm(15359):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d71628 self=0x22eea8
03-30 12:48:56.644: I/dalvikvm(15359):   | sysTid=15404 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2056240
03-30 12:48:56.651: I/dalvikvm(15359):   | schedstat=( 3387725830 799926751 876 ) utm=327 stm=10 core=0
03-30 12:48:56.651: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:~91)
03-30 12:48:56.651: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
03-30 12:48:56.651: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at android.graphics.YuvImage.nativeCompressToJpeg(Native Method)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at android.graphics.YuvImage.compressToJpeg(YuvImage.java:141)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at com.vfranchi.camerafluid.SavePhotoTask.doInBackground(SavePhotoTask.java:78)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at com.vfranchi.camerafluid.SavePhotoTask.doInBackground(SavePhotoTask.java:1)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-30 12:48:56.667: I/dalvikvm(15359):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-30 12:48:56.683: W/System.err(15359): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-30 12:48:56.683: W/System.err(15359):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
03-30 12:48:56.683: W/System.err(15359):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
03-30 12:48:56.691: W/System.err(15359):    at android.graphics.YuvImage.nativeCompressToJpeg(Native Method)
03-30 12:48:56.691: W/System.err(15359):    at android.graphics.YuvImage.compressToJpeg(YuvImage.java:141)
03-30 12:48:56.691: W/System.err(15359):    at com.vfranchi.camerafluid.SavePhotoTask.doInBackground(SavePhotoTask.java:78)
03-30 12:48:56.691: W/System.err(15359):    at com.vfranchi.camerafluid.SavePhotoTask.doInBackground(SavePhotoTask.java:1)
03-30 12:48:56.691: W/System.err(15359):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-30 12:48:56.698: W/System.err(15359):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-30 12:48:56.698: W/System.err(15359):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-30 12:48:56.698: W/System.err(15359):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-30 12:48:56.698: W/System.err(15359):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-30 12:48:56.698: W/System.err(15359):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-30 12:48:56.706: W/System.err(15359):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-30 12:48:56.706: D/skia(15359): ------- write threw an exception
03-30 12:49:15.181: W/jdwp(15359): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
03-30 12:49:15.181: I/dalvikvm(15359): GC lifetime allocation: 5 bytes
```

The YuvImage buffer is created on the onPreviewFrame which is shown below:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
{
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

    // Generate a YuvImage from the camera data
    int w = size.width;
    int h = size.height;
    YuvImage photoImage = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), w, h, null);
    mPhotoBuffer.add(0, photoImage);

    if (mPhotoBuffer.size() > mBufferSize)
    {
        mPhotoBuffer.remove(mPhotoBuffer.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: process one at a time, instead of loading all of them into memory

Comment: I need to have a buffer of frames in order to apply the effect I want to. I can buffer up to 32 frames with no problem at all. Only when I try to compress them to Jpeg I get the memory error.

And I process them one at a time inside the **for** loop, calling `System.GC();` in the end. What you are telling me is to make the AsyncTask process only one and when it's finished I execute it another time for another frame? Is that it?

Comment: System.gc() is useless so forget about that. Inside the loop you are processing one at a time try to write that buffer some temporary cache and then load and process image one at a time. If possible try to minimize number of image on your buffer.

Comment: I'll try to save the buffer on the external storage before I execute the AsyncTask. Then, on it, I'll load, process and release each image from the disk. Do you think it'll work?

Comment: Yes try that and make sure after writing to file your memory is actually free.

Comment: It didn't work. I guess it changed something, it manages to process 2 images, then, it crashes with Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x413a0098 (code=2). I'll update the post with my current code.

Comment: Now I already tried processing this on a Thread instead of an AsyncTask, just to see if something would go different, but no luck, same issue.

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to try, I changed the AsyncTask to process only one image. When it was finished, it notifies the MainActivity that creates a Thread to wait for 2 seconds and then create another task to process the next image. Still crashing on the third image with the same Fatal signal 11. This Fatal signal is related to a memory heap error, but it's different from the OutOfMemory expection I was getting in the beggining.

Comment: You are getting segmentation error which is a access violation, i can not debug your code but please make sure that the images are not corrupted while read and write operation. It is also need to understand that why two images processed without error and what wrong with third one. May be different sets of images will reveal something else. You can also try running your code only on first two images and see the effect. Also try to use different image. What bugging me  is you are getting access violation which basically mean something is corrupted somewhere.

Comment: The images are camera frames, I'm saving the YuvImage on the onPreviewFrame. When I touch the screen it calls the takePhoto method which is saving the currently 5 YuvImage and executing the AsyncTask. I'm adding the onPreviewFrame code as well.

Comment: I guess it has nothing to do with the third image but with the third time I call compressToJpeg method. Look at the most recent doInBackground method, I am processing only the first image repeatedly and on the third time I got OutOfMemory again. I also updated the LotCat with the Exception.

Comment: So far your code looks ok to me, good thing is you do not have access violation anymore. Only think i can see from the code above is set to YuvImage to null, in the for loop after writing image to file. Based on current code heap memory should be same before and after executing doItBackground and takePhoto method. More specifically it should be same after starting the loop and end of loop. Try use this sample code which will show you current heap memory status at least you will be see the real status . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766898/monitor-the-memory-ocuppied-by-my-app-in-android

Comment: Actually I did a workaround for my problem. I stopped using YuvImage and instead used a custom YUV to RGB decoder found here in StackOverflow, then I created a Bitmap and called the `compress()` method. Everything worked that way. I'll post the answer in a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for my problem, and it was by not using YuvImage class. I guess something is wrong with the `compressToJpeg()` method, at least on my device I don't know.

Here is the final code for my **doInBackground** method:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) 
{
    int lineHeight = mHeight / mBufferSize;
    int currentHeight = 0;

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(result);

    Log.d("output", "saving photo: "+mWidth+", "+mHeight);
    File outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/camerafluid-output");
    outputPath.mkdirs();
    for (int i = 0; i < mBufferSize; i++)
    {
        File imageFile = new File(mCachePath, "image-"+i);
        File outputFile = new File(outputPath, "image-"+i+".jpg");

        if (!imageFile.exists())
        {
            Log.d("output", "image "+i+" not found on cache directory");
            continue;
        }

        try
        {
            int size = (int)imageFile.length();
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[size];
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
            buf.read(imageBytes, 0, size);
            buf.close();

            int[] imagePixels = MainActivity.convertYUV420_NV21toRGB8888(imageBytes, mWidth, mHeight);
            imageBytes = null;
            Bitmap bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagePixels, mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            imagePixels = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (!bitmapImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out))
            {
                Log.d("output", "problem converting yuv to jpg");
                break;
            }

            FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            s.write(out.toByteArray());
            s.flush();
            s.close();
            s = null;

            currentHeight += lineHeight;
            Log.d("output", "currentHeight: "+currentHeight);

            publishProgress((int)((i / (float)mBufferSize) * 100));
            System.gc();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if (isCancelled())
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

The method is converting the Yuv data to RGB and creating a bitmap so I can compress to JPEG and save to the external storage. This was only for testing purposes, and this way, there is no Signal error 11 or an OutOfMemory exception. I already tried with a buffer of 40 images.

The YUV -> RGB converter was found here [Displaying YUV Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272388/extract-black-and-white-image-from-android-cameras-nv21-format/12702836#12702836). And I'm using **minhaz** idea to cache the buffer on disk before processing the images to avoid high memory usage.

Comment: Wonder solution. Thanks a lot.