# Remove onFlyCompress message from logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I am using `YuvImage` to compress the `android.hardware.Camera` feed to jpeg. Since then, I keep seeing `skia onFlyCompress` messages in logcat, which completely pollutes it. Is there any way to disable this message? I know I can filter the logcat output but that means doing it everywhere all the time, which is not a fix but a workaround. I simply don't want those messages printed at all

Comment: Does this affect release build of your app? Skia uses DEBUG priority for these messages, they should only be present in a debug build.

Comment: do you restart your devices and then try to debug it.

Comment: this amy help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696165/out-of-memory-when-using-compresstojpeg-on-multiple-yuvimage-one-at-a-time

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511433/how-to-exclude-certain-messages-by-tag-name-using-android-adb-logcat/29634795) question?

Comment: @shakram02 Do you accept what runs on rooted devices?

Comment: I wanted to fix it actually, not just remove the log message. I compress YuvImages and that's what caused the message. I didn't know about XPosed, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

You may can (i am not sure) subclass the class `YuvImage` which prints log and override the method of that class which prints the log and simply copy all code of that method but the `Log.d()` or `Log.v()` or `Log.w()` , ... code to the overridden method.

Look at the following answer too:

[How do I enable/disable log levels in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018263/how-do-i-enable-disable-log-levels-in-android/2019563#2019563)

Comment: `android.util.Log` is a final class and can't be overridden. Anyway the called methods are static and therefore overriding won't help.

Comment: @Robert there is no need to override `android.util.Log` or its methods .However if called method of `YuvImage` is static you may can copy codes to your class and change them as you want. you need to have source codes in this way

Comment: Right, I misinterpreted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Try accomplishing your goal with **method hooking**.

You can hook `android.util.log` methods using **[XPosed Framework](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial)** 
on *ROOTed* devices.

**Detailed methods**

1. Use XPosed Framework to hook the `android.util.Log`'s methods.
2. In the hooking method, check if the message contains `skia onFlyCompress`.
3. If then call `setResult(null);` to prevent it from printing out the log message.

**Though** these methods **can only be used on rooted devices,** but I hope my answer help *at least* some users that can use rooted devices.

(Hmm, because **no customers** will have to block the log messages, so all you need to do is to just root **your** local device **only** and install the auto-filtering app that uses XPosed framework.)

To see an example of blocking a method from executing rest of its code: 
[This answer(especially the last paragraph)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379762/8614565) contains some examples to use Xposed framework. As you can see, the codes are **very short(no longer than 40 lines.)**

I will implement some codes if needed/seen potentially useful.

**Sample code snippet**

As someone upvoted mine, I assume that someone liked my suggestions. So I post some codes.

```
import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class LogFilterApp implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{

    private String TAG="LogFilter";
     public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable
{
    XposedBridge.log("Package name: " + lpparam.packageName);

            try
            {
                    findAndHookMethod("android.util.Log", lpparam.classLoader, "i", String.class, String.class, new XC_MethodHook()
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable
                        {
                            //do something before
                            if(((String)(param.args[1])).indexOf("skia onFlyCompress")>=0)
                                                          { 
                                                          param.setResult(null);
                                                           }
                        }
                    });
            }
            catch (XposedHelpers.ClassNotFoundError e)
            {
                XposedBridge.log("ClassNotFoundError");
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodError e)
            {
                XposedBridge.log("NoSuchMethodError");
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Code reference: this [XDA thread](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/hook-android-util-log-methods-t2828663/amp/)

[Install XPosed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

[XPosed Dev tutorial](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial)

Comment: The Windows related part at the beginning is a bit misleading - I would remove it because it diverts the readers attention from the Xposed idea - which is quite good. Especially because the problem is only relevant on the used debugging device.

Comment: @Robert You are definitely right. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: @Robert Applied your suggestions.